# Cannot deploy smart contract In remix

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, remix, metamask

I am trying to deploy a smart contract in remix, I have metamask and my eth balance should be enough (0.21ETH). But I cannot deploy the smart contract with no error display. What should I do.

Answer (score 0):

There are some little configurations have to be set first, please check:

1. if your link is using http instead of https
2. if you have logged
   in Metamask
3. if you have turned off the privacy mode in Metamask

Comment: or you can refer to here to see the screenshot:
https://medium.com/kepler-blockchain-lab/cannot-deploy-smart-contract-in-remix-ethereum-with-metamask-injected-web3-ee6ea73c67b6